# How to change "hostname" while running sbt run?

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt run defaults binds to 127.0.0.1 but i want to bind it to local ip address of the machine.

I have tried to do: sbt run host 192.168.2.123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sbt run` executes the main class in your project. I'm assuming you're running one of the modern web frameworks in your project.

- Play project you can probably use `-Dhttp.address=<local-ip-address>`
- Akka HTTP - `Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "<local-ip-address>", <port>)`

Comment: In case of mine, I have used http4s-server where we can provide ip-address as mentioned by you.
`BlazeBuilder.bindHttp(8080, "0.0.0.0")`
Thanks for your answer